# Prevent selecting the same value in dynamic rows with select?

Tags: php, mysql, select, dynamic, row

**Picture my task**
[image]

I have dynamic rows with select. I want that when the user selects any item from dropdown 1, then that item should be disabled in dropdown 2 and 3. Also, if an item is selected in dropdown 2, then both selected items must be disabled from dropdown 3. etc

**My code HTML :**

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th width="40%" class="text-center">Nama Barang</th>
    <th class="text-center">Grade A</th>
    <th class="text-center">Grade B</th>
    <th class="text-center">Rusak</th>
    <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btnAdd">+</button></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<select class="selectReason" name="reasontxt[]" required>
<option value=""  selected="" disabled="">-- Silahkan Pilih --</option>
<optgroup label="Nama Barang">
    <?php
    include ("../assets/config/config.php");
    $perintah= mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from barang order by nm_barang asc");
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($perintah))
    {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo "$data[id_barang]"; ?>"><?php echo "$data[nm_barang]"; ?> 
    (<?php echo "$data[dimensi]"; ?>) <?php } ?></option>
    </optgroup>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="gradeatxt[]" placeholder="Grade A" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return hanyaAngka(event)" required /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="gradebtxt[]" placeholder="Grade B" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return hanyaAngka(event)" required /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="rusaktxt[]" placeholder="Rusak" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return hanyaAngka(event)" required /></td>
    <td style="display:none;">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btnRemove">x</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**My code javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".selectReason").select2({dropdownParent: $('#TambahData .modal-content'),width:'100%'});

    $(".btnAdd").on("click", function() {
    $(".selectReason").select2("destroy");
    var row = $(".item").find("tbody").find("tr:last");
    var clone = row.clone();

    clone.find("input, select").attr("disabled", false).val("");
    clone.find("td:last").show();
    clone.find(".btnRemove").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
    row.after(clone);
    $(".selectReason").select2({dropdownParent: $('#TambahData .modal-content'),width:'100%'});
    clone.show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can add the value of a select item to a javascript array and then whenever you clone the row, you can remove the items that you have got in the array. Also, when you are cloning the row, you are creating and destroying all the select dropdowns again and again.. You should add an id to the select statements.. some unique id or class to each select dropdown and then initialize the select2 jquery.

Comment: can you help me ? @AmanjotKaur

Comment: Try once and follow the steps that I have listed...

Comment: I was very confused :D @AmanjotKaur